# How to make the ReactiveUI Select when property changed in specific conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI in WPF and I have a Listbox which bind to `SearchResults`

Now I want the `SearchResults` change when any of the two properties has changed, so I did this

```cs
_searchResults = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchTerm, x => x.SelectedItem.Deleted)
                .Select(item => item)
                .Select(item => SearchProjects(item.Item1))
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.SearchResults);
```

But I want to add some additional conditions to this.

**I want to select value only when the the `Deleted` turn from `false` to `true`.**

Can someone tell me what should I do, thank you!!!

The complete process is:

I have a listbox with datasource, and the datasource row has property `Deleted`. After I clicked a delete button of `SelectedItem`, I do something with database, and refresh the listbox datasource by change the `SelectedItem.Deleted` to `true`. The whole process is the same as I want.

But in the end, when I select another Item of the listbox, It refreshes because the `Deleted` changed to `false`. I must select the item again
because of this refresh.

So I want it to trigger only when `Deleted` changed from `false` to `true`

Comment: try `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchTerm, x => x.SelectedItem.IsShow, x => x.SelectedItem.Deleted, (term, isShow, deleted) => (isShow == false || deleted == true) ? term : (string)null).Where(x => x != null)`

Comment: @GlennWatson Thank you, I tried it and it didn’t work. My purpose is to prevent its Select behavior.

Comment: @HaoGuo: So do something like `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedItem.Deleted).Where(_ => SelectedItem.Deleted)`, i.e. react on the property and check its current value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for someone in need, I soluted it by:

```cs
_searchResults = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchTerm)
                .CombineLatest(this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedItem.Deleted)
                                   .Buffer(2, skip: 1)
                                   .Where(item => item[1] == true))
                .Select(item => item.First)
                .Select(item => SearchProjects(item))
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.SearchResults);

SelectedItem.Deleted = true;
```

or

```cs
_searchResults = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchTerm)
                .CombineLatest(this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedItem.Deleted)
                                   .Buffer(2))
                .Select(item => item.First)
                .Select(item => SearchProjects(item))
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.SearchResults);

SelectedItem.Deleted = true;
```

The `SelectedItem.Deleted = true;` is for trigger it once, so as to be able to observe subsequent changes.